# Display figure corresponding to certain handle (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, handle

In my MATLAB code I create several figures and store their handles. Due to some operations, all the figures need to be closed. How do I open the figure corresponding to one of the saved handles?

```
x=0:0.01:1;
y=x.^2;
h1 = plot(x,y);
...
close all
...
"What next?"
```

Comment: Been a little while since I had a copy of matlab, but I'm pretty sure close deletes the figure.  Maybe you can get away with turning visibility off?  Alternatively, save to a file?

Answer (score 0):

That's more of a workaround than an efficient solution, but if you can afford the memory/variable creation, you could use getframe to save the content of the figure while it's open, and after it's closed display it again:

```
clc
clear

x = 1:10;

y = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);

h1 = plot(x,y);

h1Frame = getframe(gcf);
MyData = h1Frame.cdata;

h2 = plot(x,y2);

close all

imshow(MyData)
```

Hope that helps despite the apparent drawbacks :). Of course you can generalize for multiple figures and handles, although I repeat this is probably not optimal. That's an interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the disk space, after you generate you figures, save them as `fig` files using [`hgsave`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsave.html) and then load them back in using [`hgload`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgload.html).

```
n = 1:10;
x = 0:0.01:1;
K = length(n)
for k = 1:K
  h = figure(k)
  y = x.^n(k);
  plot(x,y)

  hgsave(h,sprintf('PowerPlot_n=%d',n(k)));
end
close all
clear all

hgload('PowerPlot_n=4.fig') %for instance
h = gca;
```

This will make a bunch of plots, close them all, delete everything, and then load one of them back into memory. The figure loaded in will have all of the `XData` and `YData` and other properties, as if you had never closed it, so it's still zoomable and editable.

I have not used them, but you may also want to take a look at [`savefig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html) and [`openfig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html).